# In XSD, is it possible to set alternative types for attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

Feel free to tell me I'm not using XML right by having a data item in an attribute instead of the tag content block... but this is an internal data management project and this is my first application using XML and I am new to XSD.

Below is a typical section of my XML describing one tier of a BOM.  If there is no size attribute, quantity is a value I'm aggregating (no need to say I need 5 nuts twice when I just need 10 nuts), but some items are single quantity of unit (length, mass, etc.) and I want to know how many of a size I need.

```
    <Part PartID="8035446-1">
        <Operation>
            <Material PartID="7731112-1" Unit="EA" Qty="5"/>
            <Material PartID="788315M" Unit="IN" Qty="7.5"/>
            <Material PartID="7886005" Unit="IN" Qty="1" Size="14"/>        
        </Operation>
    </Part>
```

Initially (below) I used `xs:int` for Qty and `xs:float` for Size.  Then I came across items like wire (example above) where I am aggregating non-integer item lengths.  So I am functioning with `xs:float` for both attributes.  I have scoured a lot of documentation and examples without success.  All the `xs:alternative` examples are based on tag content types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Parts">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Part" type="PartType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Group" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="PartType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Operation" type="OperationType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="PartID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Phantom" type="xs:string" default="M"/>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="OperationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Material" type="MaterialType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="WC" type="xs:string" default="TACwip"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="MaterialType">
    <xs:attribute name="PartID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Unit" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Qty" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Size" type="xs:float" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The other option I was considering was to leave it as `xs:float` and try to write an `xs:assert` statement to check that Qty is `xs:int` when the Size attribute is present.  My problem is I can't seem to find XPath statements that allow me to evaluate field types.

Again, I'm not using XML per exact intent getting me into a use-case that shouldn't be, but now that I'm here I would rather not refactor work done to date.  And I'll live if I don't resolve this but it is eating at the back of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an XSD 1.1 processor, xs:alternative allows you to define alternative complex types for an element based on the value of one/some of its attributes. The alternative complex types define both the permitted element content and the permitted attributes. So yes, what you are trying to do is possible in XSD 1.1.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try.  I guess the existing examples and documentation just gave me the impression that this was not possible.  Some other critical stuff just came up so it will probably take me a couple days before I get a chance to fiddle with this again, so if I don't have a finished response having tested this for a while don't feel like I'm ignoring this.